# Malformed URL Exception on Java Applet in Safari

Tags: java, safari, applet

I was wondering if this is just me or what.  I've written an applet that works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, but when I try it on Safari, it immediately dies on init.  The thing is, my init function doesn't really do anything but print out "Initialized" to the java console.

I get the following in the java console (Note my "Initialized" debugging message):

```
Initialized
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.checkLiveConnectCaller(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.liveconnect.SecureInvocation.CallMethod(Unknown Source)
```

I'm starting to think it's a Safari problem since the act of trying to start an applet makes it fail.

Comment: There is not enough context to answer the question (= we need code). Are you somehow accessing your applet with JavaScript, or JavaScript from your applet?

Comment: I am using javascript to construct a button to launch the applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Safari doesn't like that the method I was calling in the applet was called "print"

I renamed it to "printDocument" and it works now.  I still get that malformed url exception, but it doesn't seem to prevent the applet from working at all.

Comment: I finally figured out the malformed url exception.  My printdocument method was overloaded (string, bool, bool) and (string, string, bool) versions.  This worked fine in windows, but java on a mac was choosing the correct one, so it was sending in a bool value as the second url string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like WebKit is removing the http://

Btw, it is not in your init function, it is URL's constructor